# How to handle several infowindows?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Each time the mouse is moving over a marker I display an infowindow:

```
var optionMarker = {position:point, map:map,icon:image,shadow:ombre};
  var marker = new g.Marker(optionMarker);
  var infowindow = new g.InfoWindow({content: texte}); 
  g.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function()
  {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);   
  });
```

If I click several markers, then I have several opened infowindows.
These infowindows are superposed.
Which could be the better way to move from a infowindow to another infowindow ?
- by clicking the selected infowindow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InfoWindows don't seem to have any events associated with them (click, mouseover, etc) so the next best thing, I think, is to manipulate the markers. I set up the markers so that when the mouse is over them, the linked InfoWindow rises to the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/XCCSL/